# Secondary Sorting (individually)

Tags: visualization, looker-studio

How would I do the Secondary sorting on a bar chart, for each individual date ? 
for example, I have data as follows

```
Date       Type       Value
1/1/2020    A1          4
1/1/2020    A2          2
1/1/2020    A3          9
1/1/2020    A4          5
1/1/2020    A5          7

2/1/2020    A1          7
2/1/2020    A2          5
2/1/2020    A3          0
2/1/2020    A4          3
2/1/2020    A5          1

3/1/2020    A1          3
3/1/2020    A2          5
3/1/2020    A3          7
3/1/2020    A4          9
3/1/2020    A5          8
```

now I need to plot daily bar chart only showing the top three maximum values of individual dates? i.e., the chart would be

```
 Date       Type       Value

    1/1/2020    A3          9
    1/1/2020    A4          5
    1/1/2020    A5          7

    2/1/2020    A1          7
    2/1/2020    A2          5
    2/1/2020    A4          3

    3/1/2020    A3          7
    3/1/2020    A4          9
    3/1/2020    A5          8
```

i.e. individual date top three, not like first sum up A1,A2,A3,A4,A5 for each date, and then sorting based on the cumulative sum.

Comment: What's your data source?

Comment: My data source is Google Cloud.

Comment: Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: Yes, @Bobbylank, I'm connecting with Google Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve the sorting you need through having Date as the dimension and Type as the breakdown dimension.

You should be able to then sort by Date and then secondary sort by type.

Restricting to 3 per date however is something you'd need to do in your data source as Data Studio can't currently do that.